# Maximize function with undetermined coefficient

Tags: functions

My question is related to this one:

[Parametric plot on multi-dimensional domain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100166/parametric-plot-on-multi-dimensional-domain)

I will use a simple example to state my pronblem.

I have a variable `f` and `g`, such as

```
f = x1+x2*Sin[t]+x3*Sin[2t];
g = x1+x2+x3;
```

`x1, x2, x3` will have some values, then I need

```
F = Maximize[{f,0<t<10},t][[1]]
```

which means `F` is the maximum of `f` as function of `t`.

Then I will make `{x1,0,10,1}, {x2,0,10,1}, {x3,0,10,1}` to obtain many `F`s and `g`s, and `Plot` `F` vs `g`.

The problems is when I write the code like this (as suggested in the Parametric plot on multi-dimensional domain):

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{F, g} /. Thread[{x1, x2, x3,->Transpose@Tuples[{Range[0, 10, 1], Range[0, 10, 1], Range[0, 10, 1]}]]
```

Or make it simple, just generate a table of `F`

```
Table[F,{x1,0,10,1}, {x2,0,10,1}, {x3,0,10,1}]
```

The problem is it seems that *Mathematica* will run the `Maximize` first, then give the `x1, x2, x3`'s value to `F`. What I want is give values to `x1, x2, x3` first, then take the maximum to obtain `F`.

Is there anyone know how to solve this.

Comment: There are errors in you `ListPlot`: a comma instead of a `}`in the `Thread` part, and `Transpose` and `ListPlot` don't have their closing `]` brackets anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do

```
f = x1 + x2*Sin[t] + x3*Sin[2 t];
g = x1 + x2 + x3;

tuples = N @ Tuples[Range[0, 10, 1], {3}];

F[i_] := Maximize[{f /. Thread[{x1, x2, x3} -> tuples[[i]]], 0 < t < 10}, t][[1]]
G[i_] := g /. Thread[{x1, x2, x3} -> tuples[[i]]]

data = Table[{G[i], F[i]}, {i, Length @ tuples}];

plot = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, FrameLabel -> {"G", "F"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you.

Comment: @QiZhong I've noticed that you haven't accepted any answer to none of your questions. If you find some answers useful/helpful, consider accepting them by clicking the gray checkmark.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the click the upper arrow is enough. Now I have clicked the checkmark. I have a problem. That is it takes about 10 minutes to run my code for 1000+points. The reason I think is the function  Maximize. Is there any way to reduce the time for running Maximize, for example reducing the precision of the result?

Comment: `Maximize` tries to find a global maximum symbolically, and is not that fast. You may try with `NMaximize` or related functions, like `FindMaximum` or so. On the other hand, 10 mins is not that long.

Comment: Do you know how to control the Precision of G[x]? For example G[4]=1.8364958495, I want G[4]=1.8365 by setting the Precision.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
f[x1_, x2_, x3_] = x1 + x2*Sin[t] + x3*Sin[2 t];
F[x1_, x2_, x3_] := Maximize[{f[x1, x2, x3], 0 < t < 10}, t][[1]]
Table[F[x1, x2, x3], {x1, 0, 10, 1}, {x2, 0, 10, 1}, {x3, 0, 10, 1}]
```

Comment: Yes, the table can work in this way. But "Transpose[{F, g} /. Thread[{x1, x2, x3,->Transpose@Tuples..." doesn't work.